# How to make included component always on top

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

How to set the background to white (view layout) below my search component? Here is my code

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include
        layout="@layout/component_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Current white background on top]

[image]

Comment: If you want the `include` to be on top of your `View` just switch their positions in your xml

Comment: You can set some elevation in your Layout which contains the elements you wish to be on the "TOP".

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the order of `include` tag and `View` tag like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/component_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update:** `android:orientation="horizontal"` was there by mistake as I edited LinearLayout to make it RelativeLayout. You don't need to add that in your RelativeLayout.

Comment: Hi @birju, I think he wants the view to be below the included layout. Your answer seems to be showing the other way around.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos Yes you're right. I forgot that there's elevation applied to the `<View>` tag. so I removed it and now I think it will be shown same as he wants (White background(`<View> tag`) below the search component)

Comment: No problem @birju. Thanks. I'm just not sure if your update has been shown here as it seems to me the way it's here it will still show the include after the view. But to be honest, I think that it's probably elevation what he's looking for here as by below he may be meaning behind instead.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos I have created an example to address his issue and I am pretty sure it works. However it can be done with `elevation` too as you suggested. The thing is elevation doesn't work on `<include>` tag so he needs to set `android:elevation="-1dp"` on `<View>` tag. Then it will work as he wants it to. But the catch here is that `elevation` property doesn't work on pre-lollipop devices. so this may be the ultimate solution for his problem. you can check output of the code I have shared here: http://prntscr.com/mixapz (Black is the included layout where as pink is the `view` tag)

Comment: Cool! Thanks @birju. Didn't know elevation doesn't work on pre-lollipop and like the -1 hack. ;)

Comment: cool thanks @FrancislainyCampos its work properly. thanks guys

Comment: Hi @birju, that's really great you got your problem sorted. Glad to help. :) if you can just please mark an answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem so that other people will know it's sorted already that would be cool. It's also a good incentive for people to keep helping others here on SO as they can be acknowledged for their contribution. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If by below you mean in the y axe, such as in a row after another, what you already have is probably fine. Having the items one after the other inside your relative layout. You can even force this position by using android:layout_toBottomOf="@+id/your_view_above"

Now if by below you mean on the z axe, the one coming down the screen in your direction, (behind) you may want to do as @amit suggested and use `elevation` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Give an `id` to the include view like `search`, 
set its `layout_alignParentTop` attribute to `true` and 
set the `View`'s `layout_below` attribute to `"@id/search"`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search"
        layout="@layout/component_search"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="1dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You don't need this attribute `android:orientation="horizontal"`, since it does not apply to a `RelativeLayout`.